# Picture Box flipping repeatedly instead of only once

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

By default, the dinosaur in the image I am using in my program is facing left but if the user presses the right key, it should flip to the right and when he presses the right key repeatedly, it should move to the right. When he presses the left key when the dinosaur is facing the right, it should flip to the left and when he presses the left key, the dinosaur should move to the left. I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
    private void moveDinos(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        bool lturn = false;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && titlePic.Visible == false)
        {
            if (lturn == true)
                dino.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
            dino.Left -= 100;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && titlePic.Visible == false)
        {
            if (lturn == false)
                dino.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
            dino.Left += 100;
        }
    }
```

I have tried many things but I can't seem to get the logic out of my mind.

Comment: Where do you set lturn and what is it? Because as of now it looks like its the state (turned left or right) and you set it to false and never change it again. And what is titlePic, it might not be visible to you but visible == false means its invisible no matter where it is.

Comment: Btw to avoid issues with keypresses use key-up or key-down so if you hold a key it counts as one.

Comment: @EpicKip if lturn is true that means left turn is possible. And there are no issues regarding the titlePic.

Comment: You have to keep track of the current side it is facing. _(stored in a field)_ If the user presses the left **again**, **it shouldn't** flip again.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen That is what I don't know, can you help me?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Ok, let me try something similar.

Comment: Make a bool turnedLeft, set it to true if you turn it left and to false if turning right. And from the code you submitted you set lturn to false every time you press a key

Comment: Your fix might be to just set the bool outside of your event handler, because you're making a new one that's false eacht time the handler is called

Comment: @NikhilRaghavendra added an answer/example: this is written in the SO editor, so there might be typos.. I forgot something, now it's complete

Answer (score 0):

Your lturn boolean is to determine the direction dino is facing? It needs to come out of the method and into the class:

```
private bool _lturn = true;
```

It can then be used in your logic as it will not always be false:

```
private void moveDinos(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left && titlePic.Visible == false)
        {
            if (_lturn != true)
            {
                dino.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
                _lturn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dino.Left -= 100;
            }
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && titlePic.Visible == false)
        {
            if (_lturn == true)
            {
                dino.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
                _lturn = false;
            }
                else
            {
                dino.Left += 100;
            }
        }
    }
```

So the if statements have also changed:

1. If direction is changed, _lturn is changed but dino doesn't move.
2. If dino is already facing direction of key press then he will move in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the current side it is facing. (stored in a field) If the user presses the left again, it shouldn't flip again.

Something like:

```
private bool _facingLeft;   // initial state of the image must match with this boolean.

private void moveDinos(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // this shoudn't depend on the visible state of the title!!! you should change it.
    if(titlePic.Visible)
        return;

    // check the keys if the left or right key is pressed.
    if((e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right))
    {

        // when the left button is pressed, it should face left..
        bool moveToTheLeft = (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left);

        // if the current state of the image facing the wrong direction?
        if(_facingLeft != moveToTheLeft)
        {   
            // if not, flip the image.
            dino.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
            // store the current facing.
            _facingLeft = moveToTheLeft;
        }
        else
            // move the dino..
            if(moveToTheLeft)
                dino.Left -= 100;
            else
                dino.Left += 100;
    }

}
```